# NCurses method to differentiate ESC and function keys without delay

Tags: c++, ncurses

Currently using WSL2, C++20, `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1`, `-lpanelw -lncursesw`.

Prior to making this post, I read several StackOverflow posts surrounding this topic. My current approach is to use `raw()`, `keypad(win, TRUE)`, `wgetch(win)`, such that pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key gives the scancode `27`, and pressing the <kbd>Right</kbd> key gives the scancode `KEY_RIGHT`. However, pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key causes a delay of 1000 ms as set by `keypad(win, TRUE)`.

Just to update the topic to the end of 2021, are there any ways to achieve the same result without the delay when pressing the `ESC` key?

Is it safe to reduce the delay by a certain percentage?

Answer (score 1):

The allowable delay depends entirely on your operating environment: if it is all *local*, no *remote* connections, it can be "shorter".  How "short" depends on how long it takes for a key sequence to appear on your application's input as well as how much error you can tolerate in distinguishing the escape character from an escape sequence.

That's documented in ncurses manual page for [`ESCDELAY`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-ESCDELAY).