# ncurses library prints weird characters on key pressed

Tags: c, process, ncurses

I have a thread that catches a key pressed through `getch` and if the key pressed is arrowUp or arrowDown then it scrolls my terminal using ncurses functions (incrementing an integer variable used to show elements from a linked list). This works fine most of the times but sometimes (usually when i hold an arrow pressed) ncurses prints on terminal weird and unexpected characters like `9;32H` (it seems like an uncatched input). Does anyone know how i can solve this?

[image: issue screenshot]

Here an MCVE

```c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

#define MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

void * listener(void* p){
    int* shift = (int*) p;
    int ch;
    while (1)
    {
        ch = getch();
        if(ch == KEY_UP){
            *shift = MAX(0, *shift - 1);
        }
        else if(ch == KEY_DOWN){
            *shift = *shift + 1;
        }
    }
}
 
int main(){
    char* c = malloc(100);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        c[i] = 'A' + (random() % 26);
    }

    int shift = 0;

    pthread_t th;

    initscr();
    raw();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    start_color();
    curs_set(0);

    pthread_create(&th, NULL, listener, (void*) &shift);

    while(1){
        for(int j = shift; j < shift+stdscr->_maxy; ++j){
            move(j-shift,0);
            clrtoeol();
            mvaddch(j-shift, 0, c[j]);
            refresh();
        }
    }

    endwin();   
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

This snippet shows my issue if you hold arrow down

**EDIT:**
The issue seems to be related to `getch()` from different thread that modifies global variables of ncurses library. Does anyone know a thread-safe way to get a char input?

Comment: Do you use multiple threads for manipulating the screen?

Comment: `9;32H` looks like the last part of an ANSI escape sequence to set cursor position. The first part might be corrupted by race condition between multiple threads.

Comment: @Gerhardh no actually the screen is handled from main thread. Others threads just modify some parameters used to print properly

Comment: How do they modify parameters? Do they tell the main thread or do they call library functions themselfes?

Comment: I use pointers in order to change parameters. I just found that i call getch from another thread, it can be related to that escape sequence?

Comment: I don't think, `getch` is involved there. But what does `I use pointers` mean? That could mean anything. If you update content while it is processed by main thread and/or ncurses, the result can get corrupted.

Comment: The main thread update the screen using parameters, like an integer representing the shift of my table. This parameters are modified from other threads passing a pointer to them. So main threads read only parameters, other threads write that parameters. Anyway ncurses functions are not called by other threads

Comment: I guess you will have to show what you do, not just describe it. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, i hope i'll be able to reproduce this error in few lines of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246540/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-daniele-affinita).

Comment: Probably a duplicate; but see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952863/ncurses-method-to-differentiate-esc-and-function-keys-without-delay/69953613#69953613).

Comment: @ThomasDickey so ESCDELAY must pass between two inputs, right?

Comment: no - `ESCDELAY` is used to decide if an escape character is by itself, or introducing a sequence of characters that should be handled as a special key.   It's not the only timeout that curses can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my issue using `getchar` instead of `getch` since it seems not to be thread safe. I found out that `getch` modifies ncurses global variable and calls `refresh()` at the end, so if another thread is changing ncurses stuff (e.g. cursor position) your program may have an unexpected behavior (in my case printing escape characters representing set cursor position)